# set value of a gridview column depending on result from MS Access query

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, ms-access, gridview

I have a query which is pulling values from a table in MS Access

```
SELECT
    tblInstructor.InstructorID,
    tblInstructor.Football AS InstructorRole,
    tblInstructor.Gym AS InstructorRole,
    tblInstructor.Yoga AS InstructorRole
FROM
    tblInstructor
WHERE
    tblInstructor.InstructorID = @InstructID
    OR tblInstructorRole.Football = 1
    OR tblInstructorRole.Gym = 1
    OR tblInstructor.Yoga = 1
```

Then i do the databind to the gridview

In my aspx page im using the following method to construct my columns within the gridview

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Instructor ID">
    <ItemTemplate >
        <asp:Label ID="lblInstructorID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("InstructorID") %>' >
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I am having the issue here where I am getting the error of multiple returns, however each instructor has only one role, so I am trying to get the role of the instructor i.e. depending on whether it is true using my sql statement above and then set the instructor role column with the role of the instructor

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Instructor Role">
     <ItemTemplate >
        <asp:Label ID="lblInstructRole" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("InstructorRole") %>' >
        </asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

My table has 3 separate field for Instructor Roles Football, Gym, Yoga which are true/false values in the Instructor timetable. I have been trying (with no luck) to get the column InstructorRole in the gridview to display the text of their role i.e.Football

I was also trying to do the following:

```
If myReader(3) = True then
    Dim Role1 As String = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem,"InstructorRole")
    Role1 = "Football"
elseif myReader(4) = true then
    Dim Role2 As String = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem,"InstructorRole")
    Role1 = "Gym"
```

If anyone could advise me what to do, I can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a Case statement in your SQL query. Your Final query will look like:

```
SELECT
tblInstructor.InstructorID,
(case when tblInstructor.Football = 1 then tblInstructor.Football
 case when tblInstructor.Gym = 1 then tblInstructor.Gym
 case when tblInstructor.Yoga = 1 then tblInstructor.Yoga
 else '' END) as InstructorRole
FROM
    tblInstructor
WHERE
    tblInstructor.InstructorID = @InstructID
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, can i ask what is the @InstructorID? Can i ask what is happening when you do this case when tblInstructor.Football = 1 then tblInstructor.Football - i am unsure of what this means. Thank you

Comment: @InstructorID, Its the query parameter, as you have used in your orignal query. Case Statement is just like Switch statement in vb.net. Just try this query, I am sure it give your 100% your desired result.

Comment: I am trying your case statement solution now and i keep getting unrecognized keyword WHEN, would you know why i would be getting this? MS Access doesn't have case statements I read would this be the reason? Thank you

Comment: @JHouston86: If this is supposed to run on MS Access you should have **really** included that in the question or in the tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the SQL query you could do it in code using Linq, something along the lines of:

```
var results = from p in [query results]
              select new {
                 // other columns you need
                 InstructorRole = formatRole(p.IsFootball, p.IsGym, p.IsYoga )
              }
```

and `formatRole` function is pretty straight forward

```
private string formatRole(bool football, bool gym, bool, yoga){
    if( football )
        return "Football";
    else if( gym )
        return "Gym";
    else if( yoga )
        return "Yoga";
    else
        // whatever the appropriate thing is, return "N/A" or throw an exception, up to you really.
}
```

You would then databind your grid to the `results` collection.

Comment: @ROMANARMY i think my sql is correct, its putting it into the gridview that im struggling with. I havent used Linq code before, is there anyway i can do it using the way i suggested above in my question? Thank you

Comment: @JHouston86: It's not a question of your SQL being correct, it's more of whether you are able to modify it or not.  Muhammad's answer is your best approach if you are able to modify SQL (no other part of the application uses it).  My approach a way to approach this if you can't (or shouldn't) modify the SQL.  The idea is that you transform the data in code into a collection you can databind to directly without any more work.